# Can the Model View Presenter be used in a native desktop application?

Tags: performance

I'm just starting out on GWT, and I came across the MVP (was actually trying to get ahead of myself..get a little motivation). I already have a desktop application that I want to modify, can a desktop application use the MVP? and if the answer is no, what components and or classes can be used to simulate having a model view presenter?

Comment: I'd answer YES to your question but you mention GWT then tag your question performance then you mention MVP and desktop applications. I sense some confusion here. Can you please clarify what you want to know.

Comment: can the MVP be used in normal java GUI programming instead of GWT? That is the main question. Then the second part is that if it can't, what classes or GUI components can I use to simulate the behaviour of an MVP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare GWT and MVP: they are totally different things.
GWT is a toolkit that allows you to write desktop-like web applications in java.
Some years ago, Ray Ryan from google gave a talk at the Google IO where he presented an effective pattern to code web applications using GWT. This pattern is MVP. It was not invented by google, it was already there. It's just fit for purpose when you come to write desktop like web applications. At least, this is what Ray Ryan proposed in his talk.
As far as I know there are 2 most famous implementations of the MVP in GWT: Acticivties and Places (Google) and GWTP (Arcbees). You can also create one yourself as exercise, it is not too complex. The main concept is having the view as dumb as possible and put all the business logic in the presenter. The View and the presenter collaborate through an interface. Ok, easier said than done, I'll give you that. But you can google for more.

So yes, you can write a desktop application using MVP.